# PayPal Button Purchase Notifications

Tags: button, paypal, squarespace, paypal-buttons

I am new to creating PayPal buttons and the owner of the small site (who is using squarespace for the site), says he isn't getting notifications of a the purchases.

How can i make sure he is getting notification of the paypal button purchases?

I would greatly appreciate any help that I can get on this.

Kind Regards,

Alex

Answer (score 0):

check the following

1. Spam or bulk Social Tab in emails; sometimes payment notifs go in
   there depending on email client; gmail etc.
2. Log into PayPal account
3. profile settings
4. my settings
5. notifications
6. Make sure: "I receive money with PayPal" is checked

If you checked all the following and they checkout ok; then open an ticket to the technical team @ https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/ / contact support link at the bottom

Hope this helps